# Laravel, executing class function from PHP wrapper file

Tags: php

I have a Laravel application where I have two PHP files, one of which is basically a wrapper with text lines and a call to a function in the other file.

When I go into powershell and run `php refresh.php`, it runs the below file but only prints out the lines, it doesn't execute the classes function, it only prints the lines out.

How can I run this refresh file so that it properly executes the refresh function in `Q_Temp.php`?

**Refresh.php**

```php
    <? php require_once ('Q_temp.php');


    echo "start \n\n";
    echo Q::refresh();
    echo "\n done \n";
    ?>
```

**Q_temp.php**

```php
    Class Q {
      function refresh()
        {
            $sql = "select C, S, P, Q FROM tbl1";
            $result_set = Iseries::runQuery_simple($sql);
            $log = "";
            foreach ($rr as $row) {
                $log .= "EXECUTING: $sql -- ";
                $res = $this->add_new($row['S'], $row['P'], $row['Q'], $row['C']);
                $log .= "$res \n";
            }
            return $log;
          }
        }
```

Comment: I think that the "correct way" to do this is creating a new [Artisan Command](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/artisan). Then run it as `php artisan mycommand`

Answer (score 1):

`$rr` in your `foreach` loop is undefined.

It should be something like this:

```php
Class Q {
  static function refresh()
    {
        $sql = "select C, S, P, Q FROM tbl1";
        $result_set = Iseries::runQuery_simple($sql);
        $log = "";
        foreach ($result_set as $row) {
            $log .= "EXECUTING: $sql -- ";
            $res = $this->add_new($row['S'], $row['P'], $row['Q'], $row['C']);
            $log .= "$res \n";
        }
        return $log;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Ah I see that now! So fixing that would allow this to run with my original command?

Comment: Ok I did fix that but now it's telling me that on line 6 of the refresh file it can't find class 'Q'